# Facebook Connect How to get userId after sign in from face book connect

Tags: facebook

i am using facebook connect it is working fine but what i want now is i want to get the information of the currently logged in user. like name, email etc. I am working in asp.net 2.0
Regards

Answer (score 0):

I woud suggest using the following project, to communicate with the facebook API:
http://facebooktoolkit.codeplex.com/Wikipage

The following page explains how to setup the project in Visual Studio and also shows how to create a Facebook session and retrieve the user info:
http://facebook.claritycon.com/help/html/64e3dc97-5125-541e-9e84-7f9303e95f06.htm

Comment: Thanks jasper. But my problem is i am using .net version 2.0 bcz my site is already in 2.0 and dll are available for 3.5.

Comment: You can take a look at this library: http://facebooknet.codeplex.com/Wikipage but it doesn't look very active.